# I can't delete my tempfile() using file.remove() in Rstudio

Tags: r, temp

I would like to delete the file I created using tempfile() by the code below.

```
tmp_filename <- tempfile()
download.file(url, tmp_filename)
dat <- read_csv(tmp_filename)
file.remove(tmp_filename)
```

However, I am constantly getting the error

> Warning in file.remove(tmp_filename) :
> cannot remove file 'C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpohBhlT\file2b447cf01240', reason 'Permission denied'".

I have already tried the method in this link:

https://www.windowscentral.com/how-take-ownership-files-and-folders-windows-10

Is there any other way to solve it? I would like to specifically use the `file.remove()` function.

Comment: Is there a reason why you want or need to use `file.remove()` (and not `remove.file()`)? Have you tried `unlink()`? What does `file.info(tmp_filename)` return?

Comment: @RuiBarradas Sorry the 'file.remove()' part was a typo, I fixed it! Yes I have tried 'unlink()', but it still doesn't remove my file. Below is the result I am getting from 'file.info(tmp_filename)'. Thanks!
C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\RtmpsBhjpv\\file740cf55a3 1736 FALSE 666 2021-09-25 09:17:28 2021-09-25 09:17:28 2021-09-25 09:23:05 no